# Extract hierarchical data from XML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Course].[Navigation](
    [NavigationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ParentID int,
    ChildID int, 
    [Type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Label] [int] NULL,
    [Id] [varchar](100) NULL 
)
```

Which represents a navigational chart for a course.

The XML that I'm trying to load is:

```xml
<navigation>
<content label="Introduction">
<content label="Intro" id="000286_1001"/>
</content>
<content label="Premature Atrial Contractions">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1002"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1003"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1004"/>
</content>
<content label="Wandering">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1005"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1006"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1007"/>
</content>
<content label="Ectopic Atrial Rhythm">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1008"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1009"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1010"/>
</content>
<content label="Supraventricular Tachycardia">
<content label="SVT" id="000286_1011"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1012"/>
<content label="Multifocal Atrial Tachycardia">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1013"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1014"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1015"/>
</content>
<content label="Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1016"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1017"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1018"/>
</content>
<content label="Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia with Block">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1019"/>
</content>
<content label="Atrial Flutter">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1020"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1021"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1022"/>
<content label="Treatment" id="000286_1023"/>
</content>
<content label="Atrial Fibrillation">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1024"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1025"/>
<content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1026"/>
<content label="Signs" id="000286_1027"/>
<content label="Treatment" id="000286_1028"/>
</content>
<content label="AVRT">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1029"/>
<content label="Pathophysiology" id="000286_1030"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1031"/>
<content label="Etiology" id="000286_1032"/>
</content>
<content label="AVNRT">
<content label="Description" id="000286_1033"/>
<content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1034"/>
<content label="Etiology" id="000286_1035"/>
</content>
<content label="Treatment" id="000286_1036"/>
</content>
<content label="Review">
<content label="Quick Quiz" id="000286_1037"/>
</content>
<content label="Conclusion">
<content label="Summary" id="000286_1038"/>
</content>
</navigation>
```

Comment: There are *lots* of Transact-SQL examples of parsing XML, including hierarchical XML, around. Perhaps you are trying to achieve a specific output that the examples you've found couldn't help you with. The more you elaborate on that, as well as on what exactly you've already tried, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost:

Forget about to use `ChildId`, keep in mind that one record can hold more than one child.

I'd suggest to use a table schema similar to next:

```
CREATE TABLE [Navigation]
(
    [NavigationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ParentID int,
    [Type] [varchar] (100) NULL,
    [Label] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Id] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LevelOrder] varchar(100)
);
```

I'll show you later how I used `LevelOrder`. As I said in my previous answer IMHO this question requires an iterative and recursive solution.

I've created this stored procedure:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getXmlHierarchy(@Xml xml, @Level int, @ParentId int, @ParentRN varchar(100))
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>     DECLARE @Label varchar(100) = '',
>             @Id varchar(100) = '',
>             @Content xml,
>             @CurrentId int = 0,
>             @NextLevel int,
>             @RN int = 1,
>             @CurrentRN varchar(100);
>
>     DECLARE curxml CURSOR LOCAL FOR
>     SELECT      l1.txt.value('@label', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
>                 COALESCE(l1.txt.value('@id', 'VARCHAR(100)'), ''),
>                 l1.txt.query('./*') content
>     FROM        @Xml.nodes('content') as l1 (txt);
>
>     OPEN curxml;
>
>     FETCH NEXT FROM curxml INTO @Label, @Id, @Content
>
>     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
>     BEGIN
>
>         SET @CurrentRN = CONCAT(@ParentRN, '/', 
>                                 REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(CAST(@RN AS VARCHAR(100)))),
>                                 CAST(@RN AS VARCHAR(100)));
>
>         INSERT INTO Navigation (ParentId, [Type], Label, Id, LevelOrder)
>         VALUES (@ParentId, 
>                 CONCAT('Level ', 
>                 CAST(@Level as VARCHAR(10))), 
>                 @Label, 
>                 @Id, 
>                 @CurrentRN);
>
>         SET @CurrentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
>         SET @NextLevel = @Level + 1;
>         SET @RN = @RN + 1;
>
>         IF CAST(@Content AS VARCHAR(MAX)) <> ''
>         BEGIN
>             EXEC getXmlHierarchy @Content, @NextLevel, @CurrentId, @CurrentRN
>         END
>
>         FETCH NEXT FROM curxml INTO @Label, @Id, @Content
>     END
>
>     CLOSE curxml;
>     DEALLOCATE curxml;
> END
> ```

**How does it work**

Basically it iterates through '' tags, inserting records one by one and, if current record has a child `<content>`, call itself recursively.

Keep in mind that to recursively call an stored procedure that uses a cursor, you must declare the cursor as LOCAL.

This procedure works for `<content>` tags so, you must get xml content after `<navigation>` tag before to call it.

> ```
> DECLARE @XmlNav xml;
> SELECT @XmlNav = xmlcol.query('navigation/*') FROM xmltab;
>
> EXEC getXmlHierarchy @XmlNav, 1, 0, '';
> ```

And this is the final result:

> ```
> SELECT NavigationId NavId, ParentId, Label, Id, LevelOrder
> FROM Navigation ORDER BY LevelOrder;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> NavId | ParentId | Label                                 | Id          | LevelOrder  
> ----: | -------: | :------------------------------------ | :---------- | :-----------
>     1 |        0 | Introduction                          |             | /001        
>     2 |        1 | Intro                                 | 000286_1001 | /001/001    
>     3 |        0 | Premature Atrial Contractions         |             | /002        
>     4 |        3 | Description                           | 000286_1002 | /002/001    
>     5 |        3 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1003 | /002/002    
>     6 |        3 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1004 | /002/003    
>     7 |        0 | Wandering                             |             | /003        
>     8 |        7 | Description                           | 000286_1005 | /003/001    
>     9 |        7 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1006 | /003/002    
>    10 |        7 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1007 | /003/003    
>    11 |        0 | Ectopic Atrial Rhythm                 |             | /004        
>    12 |       11 | Description                           | 000286_1008 | /004/001    
>    13 |       11 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1009 | /004/002    
>    14 |       11 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1010 | /004/003    
>    15 |        0 | Supraventricular Tachycardia          |             | /005        
>    16 |       15 | SVT                                   | 000286_1011 | /005/001    
>    17 |       15 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1012 | /005/002    
>    18 |       15 | Multifocal Atrial Tachycardia         |             | /005/003    
>    19 |       18 | Description                           | 000286_1013 | /005/003/001
>    20 |       18 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1014 | /005/003/002
>    21 |       18 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1015 | /005/003/003
>    22 |       15 | Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia            |             | /005/004    
>    23 |       22 | Description                           | 000286_1016 | /005/004/001
>    24 |       22 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1017 | /005/004/002
>    25 |       22 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1018 | /005/004/003
>    26 |       15 | Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia with Block |             | /005/005    
>    27 |       26 | Description                           | 000286_1019 | /005/005/001
>    28 |       15 | Atrial Flutter                        |             | /005/006    
>    29 |       28 | Description                           | 000286_1020 | /005/006/001
>    30 |       28 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1021 | /005/006/002
>    31 |       28 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1022 | /005/006/003
>    32 |       28 | Treatment                             | 000286_1023 | /005/006/004
>    33 |       15 | Atrial Fibrillation                   |             | /005/007    
>    34 |       33 | Description                           | 000286_1024 | /005/007/001
>    35 |       33 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1025 | /005/007/002
>    36 |       33 | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           | 000286_1026 | /005/007/003
>    37 |       33 | Signs                                 | 000286_1027 | /005/007/004
>    38 |       33 | Treatment                             | 000286_1028 | /005/007/005
>    39 |       15 | AVRT                                  |             | /005/008    
>    40 |       39 | Description                           | 000286_1029 | /005/008/001
>    41 |       39 | Pathophysiology                       | 000286_1030 | /005/008/002
>    42 |       39 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1031 | /005/008/003
>    43 |       39 | Etiology                              | 000286_1032 | /005/008/004
>    44 |       15 | AVNRT                                 |             | /005/009    
>    45 |       44 | Description                           | 000286_1033 | /005/009/001
>    46 |       44 | ECG Features                          | 000286_1034 | /005/009/002
>    47 |       44 | Etiology                              | 000286_1035 | /005/009/003
>    48 |       15 | Treatment                             | 000286_1036 | /005/010    
>    49 |        0 | Review                                |             | /006        
>    50 |       49 | Quick Quiz                            | 000286_1037 | /006/001    
>    51 |        0 | Conclusion                            |             | /007        
>    52 |       51 | Summary                               | 000286_1038 | /007/001
> ```

As you can see, you can use `LevlOrder` as an hierarchical field to query or to order the result set.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f0d362422130f3a0100fcf376caf4116)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop one level at a time.
Use [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) with [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) to capture the generated `NavigationId` along with the XML that will have that id as a `ParentId`.

```
declare @X xml = '
<navigation>
  <!-- XML goes here -->
</navigation>';

declare @Level int = 1;
declare @T table(ParentID int, Content xml, Level int);
insert into @T(Content, Level) values(@X.query('/navigation/content'), 1);

while 1 = 1
begin
  merge dbo.Navigation as T
  using (
        select T.ParentID,
               C.X.value('@label', 'varchar(100)') as Label,
               C.X.value('@id', 'varchar(100)') as Id,
               C.X.query('content') as Content
        from @T as T
          cross apply T.Content.nodes('content') as C(X)
        where T.level = @Level
        ) as S
  on 0 = 1
  when not matched by target then
    insert (ParentID, Label, Id)
      values(S.ParentID, S.Label, S.Id)
  output inserted.NavigationId,
         S.Content,
         @Level + 1
    into @T(ParentID, Content, Level);

  if @@rowcount = 0
    break;

  set @Level += 1;

end;
```

[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=52cd04d9d503a8d0087ad7fb88b8780f)

Ref: [Dr. OUTPUT or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the MERGE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx)